# ASP.NET MVC DisplayModeProvider with .aspx engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mobile

I am working on MVC-4 project which is using ASPX engine (not RAZOR!) and Site.Master as master page.

Now my task is to enable this site for mobile devices. After finding all available information I know, I need to do following tasks with Razor

1. Add DisplayModeProvider in Application Startup.
2. Create _Layout.Phone.cshtml and add jQuery mobile support.
3. Create phone supported Views like Index.Phone.cshtml and use _Layout.Phone.cshmtl as master page.

Now my question is how can I enable site for mobile devices using ASPX engine.

I created Site.Phone.Master and Index.Phone.aspx but it is only rendering default Web page view not Phone view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start by creating a MasterPage for the Mobile browsers (`~/Views/Shared/Site.Mobile.Master`):

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    This is the mobile master page

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
</body>
</html>
```

and then have a a mobile view (`~/Views/Home/Index.Mobile.aspx`) that will be using this masterpage:

```
<%@ Page 
    Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Mobile.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" 
%>

<asp:Content ID="indexContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    This is the mobile view
</asp:Content>
```

Alright, now all that's left is to insert the display mode in your `Application_Start`:

```
Func<HttpContextBase, bool> contextCheckDelegate = ctx =>
{
    // Here you could use the ctx variable which represents the HttpContextBase
    // in order to test the UserAgent of the Request and decide whether it is coming
    // from a mobile device or not and return true or false respectively which is what
    // will determine if your .Mobile masterpage and view will be used for this request
    if (IsMobile)
    {
        return true;
    }         
    return false;
};
DefaultDisplayMode mobileMode = new DefaultDisplayMode("Mobile");
mobileMode.ContextCondition = contextCheckDelegate;
DisplayModeProvider.Instance.Modes.Insert(0, mobileMode);
```

You could of course have more specific mobile views such as iPhone, iPad, ... where you would only need to adapt the condition used inside delegate which is checking the user agent.